# Identifier "TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32" is undefined

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create of snapshot of all modules for a specific process using the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function from `TlHelp32.h`. The first argument `dwflags` specifies which portions of the system to include in the snapshot. The `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` only includes 64 bit modules while the `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` also includes 32 bit modules which I need.

Running my code on my main pc gives no problems at all and works perfectly. On my laptop it gives the error in the title of the post and `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` is nowhere to be found inside the `TlHelp32.h` header file.

[image: Picture showing the error.]

EDIT:
I reinstalled windows for a reason that has nothing to do with this question and now everything works fine.

Comment: The picture doesn't show an error. It shows something that could be produced by Intellisense (in which case I'd just ignore it if it compiles). Please copy/paste the full **compilation error** into the question as text - not as a picture.

Comment: Check the timestamp of tlhelp32.h. If it is very old (before 2006) then you have an ancient SDK version that did not yet support 64-bit development. If it is very new and doesn't match other .h files then you accidentally edited the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it is TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, and the header file to include is tlhelp32.h, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot). If you are unable to find that identifier in tlhelp32.h, check if you have installed the correct version of Windows SDK.

Comment: Where is the typo? Is it in the picture? If so, I can't see it. What has OP written instead of the correct identifier `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32`?

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo, the question text initially had TH32_SNAPMODULE32, it is later edited. Moreover, the header file is tlhelp32.h , and **not** tl32help.h

Comment: I see. The picture has shown the correct identifier all the time though so I guess OP was a bit sloppy when writing the question.